# How Can I Install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-framework, sqlite

I'm trying to install SQlite from Nuget but I got an error. I'm using NET Core 2.1.

What should I do?

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)
```

Comment: The error message says it's not compatible. Apparently it requires Net Core 3.0.

Comment: Yes, it's true. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your error says itself that it's not compatible with Dot Net core 2.1. You need to install Dot net core version 3.0 in your project.

Hope this will  help you.
Thank you.